# how to give dynamic input to the toast while clicking the textview label?

Tags: android

In my application two projects displayed on the landing page .I want give dynamic input  to the toast while on click the label.any can help me...

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't seem too clear, but when you make a Toast, you can use variables as part of the String message you are to display. So if you have a variable that is connected to some sort of input from the user, you can use it there, as long as you convert it to string by calling the toString() method or summing it with an empty string (or the static part of the message you want to display): +""